# ng-controller error in index.html "The controller with the name 'MainController' is not registered"

Tags: angularjs, components

I have been looking for an answer to this for a while now, and at first glance it seems similar to other controller registration issues with angularJS, but there hasn't been a good answer for my particular use case yet.

I am in the middle of a complicated refactor of our legacy angularJS app. The first step is to get everything into components, and then we will begin upgrading to Angular 2+.

My issue is the MainController. I have converted it to a component as detailed below:

```
const MainControllerComponent = {
  selector: 'mainController',
  templateUrl: '../../index.html',
  bindings: {},
  controller: class MainController {

  constructor() {
    ...constructor stuff
  }
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .component(MainControllerComponent.selector, MainControllerComponent);
```

The index HTML that uses this controller is as follows:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

  <body id="mainController" ng-controller="MainController as main" ng-class="{ 'is-mobile':   $ctrl.isMobile, 'is-desktop': !$ctrl.isMobile, 'anon': !$ctrl.isUserAuthenticated, 'walkthrough': $ctrl.isWalkthrough(), 'root-controller': $ctrl.isRootController() }" class="{{bodyClass}}">
    ...Other body html stuff
  </body>
</html>
```

The app compiles (we are using gulp/sass), but will not load. I get the following error:

`[$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'MainController' is not registered.`

in app.js we are using require() to include all of the js/ts in the build

`require('./js').default(ngModule);`

And the controllers folder is indexed like so:

```
export default ngModule => {
  require('./activate_controller').default(ngModule); //Not yet converted
  require('./activity_controller');  //converted and works
  
  ...

  require('./login_controller').default(ngModule); //not yet converted
  require('./main_controller'); //converted and won't register

  ...
};
```

So I am at a loss. I have tried renaming the reference in the ng-controller to the component name. Unlike many other examples here, the app name is correct, and the app compiles with gulp. If I removed the ng-controller attribute, the app loads, but all of the main functionality is broken (No header/menu, etc) but child controllers work as intended. So it seems to be just an issue with getting the index.html to see the new component as a valid controller.

What am I doing wrong here? I even tried adding a dummy entry into our router.js (which defines $stateProvider for our app) and it did nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`mainController` in the selector but `MainController` in the `ng-controller`

You have a casing difference.